# Return the index of an arbitrary Object in a 2d array java.

Tags: java, arrays, object, indexing

I'm trying to find the index of an object placed in an array. The array has been populated like this

```
for(i = 0 ; i<n ;i++){
    for(j=0; j<n ;j++){
        squares[i][j]= new Square(i,j)
        }
```

So the array is basically full of Square objects with no name. I want to make a method that returns the index of a square object, like:

```
getObject(Square s){
{
```

I've seen other answers calling for the use of

```
Arrays.asList(array)
```

And stuff like that, but they all try to return the index for an int or a String.

How should i go about returning the index for any object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the comparison operator (`equals()` method) of your `Square` is suitable for you, then any of these method would work :

- Converting to `ArrayList` and unsing `indexOf` and `get`
- Using `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch`
- Do a `foreach` loop and search manually
- etc.

You only need a valid comparison operator, if the default `Object.equals()`(comparison of object instances) is suitable for your need, then you don't have much to do :

```
Point getObject(Square s){
{
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            if( squares[i][j].equals(s) ) {
                return Point(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that if your array is large, it's not the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use equals method (assuming n is defined also, or you can use length) :

```
public int[] getObject(Square s){

int[] returnIndex = new int[2];

for(int i = 0 ; i<this.n ;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<this.n ;j++){ 

        if(s.equals(this.squares[i][j])) {
               returnIndex[0] = i;
               returnIndex[1] = j;
               return returnIndex;
            }

       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved like this

```
private ArrayList<Square> squareList= new ArrayList<Square>(9);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                mSquare[i][j] = new Square(i, j);
                squareList.add(mSquare[i][j]);
            }
        }

    public int index(int r, int c) {
        return squareList.indexOf(Square(r, c));
    }
```